# How do I keep my input focused when updating a live view?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a live view that adds a `p` tag with `typing...` when a user updates an text input in form element. I want it to remove `typing..` when the user blurs out of the text input.

```
<section class="phx-hero">
  <%= if @typing do %>
    <p>typing...</p>
  <% end %>
  <form phx-change="typing" phx-submit="send-message">
    <input type="text" phx-blur="stopped-typing" name="msg" value="<%= @msg %>" placeholder="Send message..."/>
    <button type="submit" phx-disable-with="Sending...">Submit</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

The events are handled with:

```
  @impl true
  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, typing: false, msg: "")}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_event("send-message", %{"msg" => msg}, socket) do
    {:noreply, assign(socket, msg: msg)}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_event("typing", %{"msg" => msg}, socket) do
    {:noreply, assign(socket, typing: true, msg: msg)}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_event("stopped-typing", _, socket) do
    {:noreply, assign(socket, typing: false)}
  end
```

The problem is that when I initially type in the input box, it loses focus and I have to click back into it to continue typing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix:

I had to wrap the `<p>typing...</>` in a parent container

```
<div>
  <%= if @typing do %>
    <p>typing...</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I think the DOM patch was updating all children of `section` when it added the "typing..." paragraph.